# Why doesn't Eliminate work as I expect?

Tags: eliminate

I am trying to use Eliminate to solve 3 loop equations in an electronic network:

[image]

```
xc[c_] := 1/s/c

loop1 = v1 - r  (i1 - i2) - xc[c1]  (i1 - i3) == 0;

loop2 = r  (i2 - i1) + xc[c2]   i2 + r  (i2 - i3) == 0;

loop3 = v2 - xc[c1]  (i3 - i1) - r  (i3 - i2) == 0;

Eliminate[{loop1, loop2, loop3}, {i1, i2, i3}]

(*True*)
```

I expected the Eliminate to return a single equation after eliminating the current variables, Then this equation could be solved for v2 in terms of v1, giving the network transfer function. Can anyone tell me where I've gone wrong?

Comment: It is because out of three equations, you can eliminate one or two of three variables, but you may solve for all three of them. `Solve[{loop1, loop2, loop3}, {i1, i2, i3}]` returns the solution.

Comment: If you try to replace i1-i2 etc by their differences using GroebnerBasis[
 First /@ {loop1, loop2, 
   loop3, (i1 - i3) == i13, (i2 - i3) == i23, (i1 - i2) == i12}, {i12,
   i13, i23}, {i1, i2, i3}] your will get {v2,v1} , which means you have no enough freedom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The node potential analysis leads to the goal more quickly.

```
eq1 = (e1 - V1)/R + e1*s*c1 + (e1 - Vout)/R == 0;
eq2 = (Vout - e1)/R + (Vout - V1)*s*c2 + Vout/RL == 0;
tf = Vout/V1 /. Solve[{eq1, eq2}, {e1, Vout}] // Expand // Together
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"];
xc[c_] := 1/(s c)

node2 = -vin (1/r ) + v2 (1/r + 1/xc[c1] + 1/r) - vout (1/r ) == 0;
nodeout = -vin (1/xc[c2] ) - v2 (1/r) + 
    vout (1/r + 1/rL + 1/xc[c2]) == 0;

sol = Solve[{node2, nodeout}, {v2, vout}];

tf = vout/vin /. sol // Simplify;

tf // (Collect[Numerator@#, s]/Collect[Denominator@#, s]) &
```

---

$\left\{\frac{\text{c1} \text{c2} r^2 \text{rL} s^2+2 \text{c2} r \text{rL} s+\text{rL}}{\text{c1} \text{c2} r^2 \text{rL} s^2+s \left(\text{c1} r^2+\text{c1} r \text{rL}+2 \text{c2} r \text{rL}\right)+2 r+\text{rL}}\right\}$

---

To make it easy to read (without using subscripted vars initially):

```
aliases = {r -> R, rL -> Subscript[R, L], c1 -> Subscript[C, 1], 
   c2 -> Subscript[C, 2]};

(tf // (Collect[Numerator@#, s]/Collect[Denominator@#, s]) &) /. 
  aliases // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Thank you both for the comments. They pointed out that I was not thinking correctly about the problem. It began with me defining the problem incorrectly. This, I believe, it the correct way -- though perhaps not the best way -- to solve the problem:

[image]

```
xc[c_] := 1/s/c
loop1 = v1 - r  (i1 - i2) - xc[c1]  (i1 - i3) == 0;
loop2 = r  (i2 - i1) + xc[c2]   i2 + r  (i2 - i3) == 0;
loop3 = rl  i3 + xc[c1]  (i3 - i1) + r  (i3 - i2) == 0;
out = vout == i3  rl;

transferFunction = 
 vout/v1 /. 
   Solve[Eliminate[{loop1, loop2, loop3, out}, {i1, i2, i3}], 
     vout][[1]] // Simplify
```

Comment: Why do you need `Eliminate`? `Solve` can take care variables elimination.

Comment: Yes, thank you. `vout/vin /. Solve[{loop1, loop2, loop3, out}, { vout, i1, i2, 
     i3}][[1]] // Simplify` also works.